# Why doesn't this background image fill its element in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, transform

Consider the following snippet:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #eee;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 20%;
  padding: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/12x12/ff9999);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Test</h4>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I expect the background image to fully fill the `.box`, which is exactly what happens in Chrome and IE11. However, Firefox doesn't quite fill the `.box`, leaving a 1-pixel sliver of white showing:

[image]

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: add a `background-size: cover;` to `.box{}`

Comment: Can't reproduced it to be honest. Test it on firefox developer edition too.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/z2pdku7e/) in Firefox, either.

Comment: Weird, I could reproduce in Firefox 34 for both Windows and Linux. @showdev - I get the white sliver when viewing your fiddle in Firefox.

Comment: @Banzay that just stretches the background image across the width of the element, which isn't what I want.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 34 on Mac. Still cannot reproduce, unfortunately. But I do see the white space in your screen-shot...

Comment: I can reproduce with Firefox 32-34 on Windows 8.1

Comment: It is also possible to use [Browserling](https://browserling.com) to reproduce this on their Firefox 32 machine.

Comment: The problem does not seem to exist with Firefox on OSX, so it is probably an actual bug in the Windows version of Firefox.  You might need to accept that the CSS is good, but a workaround is still needed....

Comment: But i can reproduce on ubuntu, linux, firefox 34

Comment: It renders perfectly in Firefox 17 on Windows, but has the defect in Firefox 18.

Comment: It seems you need to make a 12px height image to fill 12px height div, so may be solution is just to add `background-origin: padding-box;`

Comment: yeah it seems there are a few different ways to get around the issue. If you comment out the Translate CSS you will notice the container and image appear as normal. You may want to position your elements using a different method.

Comment: without this: `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` all works perfectly

Comment: For the record, I've filed a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1107671

Comment: @NathanOsman Making the internet better one step at a time!